# How to deactivate creatives using Google ads api Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-ads-api

- I have managed to get the Ids of all the creatives I want deactivating, I now need to deactivate them.
- documentation from google:https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v202205/CreativeService#performCreativeAction

```
 for(const creativeId of mainArray){
      const deactCreat = await CreativeService.performCreativeAction({
        filterStatement:{
          query:  `WHERE creativeId = '${creativeId}'`,
          creativeAction: DeactivateCreatives
        }
        
      })
    }
```

```
 for(const creativeId of mainArray){
      const deactCreat = await CreativeService.performCreativeAction({
        filterStatement:{
          query:  `WHERE creativeId = '${creativeId}'`,
          DeactivateCreatives
        }
        
      })
    }
```

```
for(const creativeId of mainArray){
      const deactCreat = await CreativeService.performCreativeAction({
        filterStatement:{
          query:  `WHERE creativeId = '${creativeId}'`,
          
        },
        CreativeAction:'DeactivateCreatives'
      })
    }
```